# Using Samsung M2024W printer from Ubuntu

Tags: printing

I recently bought a small Samsung M2024W laser printer, and I'm trying to use it from Ubuntu 18.04. I've used a M2020W in the past, and it was auto-detected and worked flawlessly. However, with the M2024W, Ubuntu says it's unable to connect even though it's connected via USB.

Googling doesn't show much info regarding Linux compatibility with this model. Is there anything I can do to get it to work?

Comment: Have you installed the samsung uld (unified linux driver)?

Comment: @NickSillito No, because according to [its website](https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/index.html), which hasn't been updated in 2 years, "the driver is unlikely to work on a completely up-to-date Linux system".

Comment: Im using a Samsung m2026w (also a 2020 series device), connected via WiFi rather than a USB cable. I've just done a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 and Samsung's uld worked fine